# Remove array without any statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have added 6 objects into `NSMutableArray` array named `games`. The 6 objects are named `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E` and `F`.

```
NSMutableArray *games = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",nil];
```

I want to remove 3 elements from `games` array, e.g. `D`, `E` and `F` should be removed from the array and `A`, `B` and `C` should remain stored in the array.

I want simple code that does not involve any loop statement.

Is it possible to remove elements from the array without using a loop?

Comment: What is NSMultipleArray??

Comment: @SalmanZaidi sorry it is mistake. updated edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code i test it in my machine it is working fine

```
 NSMutableArray *games = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",nil];

    NSRange r;
    r.location = 3;
    r.length = [games count]-3;
    [games removeObjectsInRange:r];
    NSLog(@"array elements are %@",games);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [NSMutableArray class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObjectsInRange%3a) and try:

```
- (void)removeObjectsInRange:(NSRange)aRange;

- (void)removeObjectsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *games = [[NSMUltipleArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",nil];

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<[myArray count]; i++) {
        id element = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if(element == ...) {
            [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            i--;
        }
    }
```

element = which element you want to remove match it

without loop

```
NSMutableArray *games = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",nil];

    NSRange remove;
    remove.location = 3;
    remove.length = [games count]-3;
    [games removeObjectsInRange:remove];
    NSLog(@"after removed elements  = %@",games);
```

Comment: I dnt want loop statement. Any idea?

Comment: then use NSRange remove;
    remove.location = 3;
    remove.length = [games count]-3;

    [games removeObjectsInRange: remove];

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm not sure if you want to throw away the last three objects of the array or to keep the first three. We'll anyway you can call `subarrayWithRange:` on the original array to get a new array with the objects you want to keep. or, if you don't want to create a new array and the original array is an NSMutable array you may use `removeObjectsInRange:`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSPredicate` to filter the array its very simple, there is no of index or Range of the specific object just **filtering predicate** is enough to filter the `array`.

```
NSMutableArray *game=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F" ,nil];
    game = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [game filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (SELF IN %@)",[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"D", @"E",@"F", nil]]]];
```